# Tests Disappearing in Issue Navigator in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, testing

I am attempting to test my code (ObjC) using the most recent version of XCode.  When I run my tests, they all quickly appear in the Issue Navigator, only to disappear shortly there after.  Does anyone know why this might be? I never changed any settings or preferences, so I'm very confused as to why it has been occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tests disappearing in Xcode's Test Navigator is a long standing problem.

Usually you can revive the Test Navigator by deleting your project's Derived Data folder.
In Xcode7 beta6 (most recent at time of writing) this can be done by:

1. Close your project if it's open.
2. Navigating to `Window menu > Projects`.
3. Choose your project from the list on the left.
4. Tap the `Delete…` button to the right of where it says `Derived Data`
5. Re-open your project and wait for indexing to complete.